# How do I remove duplicates from a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

I have been working with a `string[]` array in C# that gets returned from a function call. I could possibly cast to a `Generic` collection, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it, possibly by using a temp array.

**What is the best way to remove duplicates from a C# array?**

Comment: Use the Distinct extension method.

Comment: Indeed. It's more fun when the array is already sorted - in that case it can be done in-place in O(n) time.

Comment: @Vitim.us Nope.  In my case, it isn't even an array, but a List<string>.  I accept any answer that does the job.  Perhaps, it's a shock of having to do it on paper.

Comment: A better way than...? And what's the idea of casting to a generic collection? Either way, to anybody feeling the urge to add yet another answer: keep in mind that the question is not "*a* way to remove duplicates" as almost everybody did. Any answer should account for time complexity and show benchmarks. So far, only two answers did a serious attempt.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

You could possibly use a LINQ query to do this:

```
int[] s = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
int[] q = s.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that you can use an IEqualityComparer as a parameter, such as `.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` to get a case-insensitive distinct set of strings.

Comment: Is Distinct honors original order of elements?

Comment: @asyrov: from MSDN : `The Distinct() method returns an unordered sequence that contains no duplicate values.`

Comment: What makes this "the best way"?

Answer (score 57):

Here is the [HashSet<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) approach:

```
public static string[] RemoveDuplicates(string[] s)
{
    HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(s);
    string[] result = new string[set.Count];
    set.CopyTo(result);
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately this solution also requires .NET framework 3.5 or later as HashSet was not added until that version. You could also use [array.Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx), which is a feature of LINQ.

Comment: This probably will not preserve the original order.

Answer (score 11):

The following tested and working code will remove duplicates from an array. You must include the System.Collections namespace.

```
string[] sArray = {"a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "f"};
var sList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < sArray.Length; i++) {
    if (sList.Contains(sArray[i]) == false) {
        sList.Add(sArray[i]);
    }
}

var sNew = sList.ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < sNew.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write(sNew[i]);
}
```

You could wrap this up into a function if you wanted to.

Comment: This appears to be O(N^2)... You could use a heap instead of an ArrayList

Answer (score 10):

If you needed to sort it, then you could implement a sort that also removes duplicates.

Kills two birds with one stone, then.

Comment: How does sorting remove duplicates?

Comment: Who voted this up?  This isn't an answer.  "How do I make pancakes?"  "Put some ingredients in a bow and mix."

Comment: Correct, it is indeed not an answer. It was a comment, made before StackOverflow _had_ comments, I believe. This question was asked when there were fewer than 10k questions on SO.

Comment: A helpful comment because I wanted to both sort and remove duplicates from my collection, and this comment gave me the idea to switch from a `List<T>` to a `SortedSet<T>` which solved my problem very succinctly.

Answer (score 8):

This might depend on how much you want to engineer the solution - if the array is never going to be that big and you don't care about sorting the list you might want to try something similar to the following:

```
    public string[] RemoveDuplicates(string[] myList) {
        System.Collections.ArrayList newList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

        foreach (string str in myList)
            if (!newList.Contains(str))
                newList.Add(str);
        return (string[])newList.ToArray(typeof(string));
    }
```

Comment: You should use List instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> List<String> myStringList = new List<string>();
> foreach (string s in myStringArray)
> {
>     if (!myStringList.Contains(s))
>     {
>         myStringList.Add(s);
>     }
> }
> ```

This is **O(n^2)**, which won't matter for a short list which is going to be stuffed into a combo, but could be rapidly be a problem on a big collection.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a **O(n*n)** approach that uses **O(1)** space.

```
void removeDuplicates(char* strIn)
{
    int numDups = 0, prevIndex = 0;
    if(NULL != strIn && *strIn != '\0')
    {
        int len = strlen(strIn);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            bool foundDup = false;
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if(strIn[j] == strIn[i])
                {
                    foundDup = true;
                    numDups++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(foundDup == false)
            {
                strIn[prevIndex] = strIn[i];
                prevIndex++;
            }
        }

        strIn[len-numDups] = '\0';
    }
}
```

The **hash/linq** approaches above are what you would generally use in real life. However in interviews they usually want to put some constraints e.g. constant space which rules out hash or no internal **api** - which rules out using **LINQ**.

Comment: How can it ever use O(1) space, when you have to store the entire list?
By starting with an inplace sort, you can do O(nlogn) time and O(n) memory, with much less code.

Comment: What makes you think it is storing the entire list? It is indeed doing in-place. And though not a condition in the question, my code maintains the order of characters in the original string. Sorting will remove that.

Comment: The inner loop (`strIn[j] == strIn[i]`) will be comparing a string to itself unless accounted for with an if statement.

Answer (score 6):

-- This is **Interview Question** asked every time. Now i done its coding.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{    
            int[] array = new int[] { 4, 8, 4, 1, 1, 4, 8 };            
            int numDups = 0, prevIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                bool foundDup = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (array[i] == array[j])
                    {
                        foundDup = true;
                        numDups++; // Increment means Count for Duplicate found in array.
                        break;
                    }                    
                }

                if (foundDup == false)
                {
                    array[prevIndex] = array[i];
                    prevIndex++;
                }
            }

            // Just Duplicate records replce by zero.
            for (int k = 1; k <= numDups; k++)
            {               
                array[array.Length - k] = '\0';             
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Console program for Remove duplicates from array.");
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't do a O(n*2) time complexity for an this question.

Comment: You should use merge sort

Answer (score 5):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = "a;b;c;d;e;v";
    string[] b = a.Split(';');
    string[] c = b.Distinct().ToArray();

    if (b.Length != c.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (b[i].ToString() != c[i].ToString())
                {
                    Response.Write("Found duplicate " + b[i].ToString());
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Found duplicate " + b[i].ToString());
                return;
            }
        }              
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("No duplicate ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add all the strings to a dictionary and get the Keys property afterwards. This will produce each unique string, but not necessarily in the same order your original input had them in.

If you require the end result to have the same order as the original input, when you consider the first occurance of each string, use the following algorithm instead:

1. Have a list (final output) and a dictionary (to check for duplicates)
2. For each string in the input, check if it exists in the dictionary already
3. If not, add it both to the dictionary and to the list

At the end, the list contains the first occurance of each unique string.

Make sure you consider things like culture and such when constructing your dictionary, to make sure you handle duplicates with accented letters correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The following piece of code attempts to remove duplicates from an ArrayList though this is not an optimal solution. I was asked this question during an interview to remove duplicates through recursion, and without using a second/temp arraylist:

```
private void RemoveDuplicate() 
{

ArrayList dataArray = new ArrayList(5);

            dataArray.Add("1");
            dataArray.Add("1");
            dataArray.Add("6");
            dataArray.Add("6");
            dataArray.Add("6");
            dataArray.Add("3");
            dataArray.Add("6");
            dataArray.Add("4");
            dataArray.Add("5");
            dataArray.Add("4");
            dataArray.Add("1");

            dataArray.Sort();

            GetDistinctArrayList(dataArray, 0);
}

private void GetDistinctArrayList(ArrayList arr, int idx)

{

            int count = 0;

            if (idx >= arr.Count) return;

            string val = arr[idx].ToString();
            foreach (String s in arr)
            {
                if (s.Equals(arr[idx]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > 1)
            {
                arr.Remove(val);
                GetDistinctArrayList(arr, idx);
            }
            else
            {
                idx += 1;
                GetDistinctArrayList(arr, idx);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe hashset which do  not  store  duplicate  elements  and  silently  ignore  requests  to  add
duplicates.

```
static void Main()
{
    string textWithDuplicates = "aaabbcccggg";     

    Console.WriteLine(textWithDuplicates.Count());  
    var letters = new HashSet<char>(textWithDuplicates);
    Console.WriteLine(letters.Count());

    foreach (char c in letters) Console.Write(c);
    Console.WriteLine("");

    int[] array = new int[] { 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };

    Console.WriteLine(array.Count());
    var distinctArray = new HashSet<int>(array);
    Console.WriteLine(distinctArray.Count());

    foreach (int i in distinctArray) Console.Write(i + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution:

```
using System.Linq;
...

public static int[] Distinct(int[] handles)
{
    return handles.ToList().Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

NOTE : NOT tested!

```
string[] test(string[] myStringArray)
{
    List<String> myStringList = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in myStringArray)
    {
        if (!myStringList.Contains(s))
        {
            myStringList.Add(s);
        }
    }
    return myStringList.ToString();
}
```

Might do what you need...

**EDIT** Argh!!! beaten to it by rob by under a minute!

Comment: Rob didn't beat you to anything. He's using ArrayList, while you're using List. Your version is better.

Answer (score 3):

Tested the below & it works. What's cool is that it does a culture sensitive search too

```
class RemoveDuplicatesInString
{
    public static String RemoveDups(String origString)
    {
        String outString = null;
        int readIndex = 0;
        CompareInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo;


        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(origString))
        {
            return outString;
        }

        foreach (var ch in origString)
        {
            if (readIndex == 0)
            {
                outString = String.Concat(ch);
                readIndex++;
                continue;
            }

            if (ci.IndexOf(origString, ch.ToString().ToLower(), 0, readIndex) == -1)
            {
                //Unique char as this char wasn't found earlier.
                outString = String.Concat(outString, ch);                   
            }

            readIndex++;

        }


        return outString;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String inputString = "aAbcefc";
        String outputString;

        outputString = RemoveDups(inputString);

        Console.WriteLine(outputString);
    }
```

}

--AptSenSDET

Answer (score 3):

This code 100% remove duplicate values from an array[as I used a[i]].....You can convert it in any OO language..... :)

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
    {
        if(a[i] == a[j])
        {
            for(int k=j;k<size;k++)
            {
                 a[k]=a[k+1];
            }
            j--;
            size--;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can using This code when work with an ArrayList

```
ArrayList arrayList;
//Add some Members :)
arrayList.Add("ali");
arrayList.Add("hadi");
arrayList.Add("ali");

//Remove duplicates from array
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.Count; i++)
    {
       for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayList.Count ; j++)
           if (arrayList[i].ToString() == arrayList[j].ToString())
                 arrayList.Remove(arrayList[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int RemoveDuplicates(ref int[] array)
{
    int size = array.Length;

    // if 0 or 1, return 0 or 1:
    if (size  < 2) {
        return size;
    }

    int current = 0;
    for (int candidate = 1; candidate < size; ++candidate) {
        if (array[current] != array[candidate]) {
            array[++current] = array[candidate];
        }
    }

    // index to count conversion:
    return ++current;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an simple logic in java you traverse elements of array twice and if you see any same element you assign zero to it plus you don't touch the index of element you are comparing.

```
import java.util.*;
class removeDuplicate{
int [] y ;

public removeDuplicate(int[] array){
    y=array;

    for(int b=0;b<y.length;b++){
        int temp = y[b];
        for(int v=0;v<y.length;v++){
            if( b!=v && temp==y[v]){
                y[v]=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic Extension method :

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    HashSet<TSource> set = new HashSet<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (set.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way? Hard to say, the HashSet approach looks fast,
but (depending on the data) using a sort algorithm (CountSort ?)
can be much faster.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random r = new Random(0); int[] a, b = new int[1000000];
        for (int i = b.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) b[i] = r.Next(b.Length);
        a = new int[b.Length]; Array.Copy(b, a, b.Length);
        a = dedup0(a); Console.WriteLine(a.Length);
        a = new int[b.Length]; Array.Copy(b, a, b.Length);
        var w = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        a = dedup0(a); Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed); Console.Read();
    }

    static int[] dedup0(int[] a)  // 48 ms  
    {
        return new HashSet<int>(a).ToArray();
    }

    static int[] dedup1(int[] a)  // 68 ms
    {
        Array.Sort(a); int i = 0, j = 1, k = a.Length; if (k < 2) return a;
        while (j < k) if (a[i] == a[j]) j++; else a[++i] = a[j++];
        Array.Resize(ref a, i + 1); return a;
    }

    static int[] dedup2(int[] a)  //  8 ms
    {
        var b = new byte[a.Length]; int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
            if (b[a[i]] == 0) { b[a[i]] = 1; c++; }
        a = new int[c];
        for (int j = 0, i = 0; i < b.Length; i++) if (b[i] > 0) a[j++] = i;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Almost branch free. How? Debug mode, Step Into (F11) with a small array: {1,3,1,1,0}

```
    static int[] dedupf(int[] a)  //  4 ms
    {
        if (a.Length < 2) return a;
        var b = new byte[a.Length]; int c = 0, bi, ai, i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        { ai = a[i]; bi = 1 ^ b[ai]; b[ai] |= (byte)bi; c += bi; }
        a = new int[c]; i = 0; while (b[i] == 0) i++; a[0] = i++;
        for (j = 0; i < b.Length; i++) a[j += bi = b[i]] += bi * i; return a;
    }
```

A solution with two nested loops might take some time,
especially for larger arrays.

```
    static int[] dedup(int[] a)
    {
        int i, j, k = a.Length - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
            for (j = i + 1; j <= k; j++) if (a[i] == a[j]) a[j--] = a[k--];
        Array.Resize(ref a, k + 1); return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static string[] distinct(string[] inputArray)
        {
            bool alreadyExists;
            string[] outputArray = new string[] {};

            for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
            {
                alreadyExists = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < outputArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (inputArray[i] == outputArray[j])
                        alreadyExists = true;
                }
                        if (alreadyExists==false)
                        {
                            Array.Resize<string>(ref outputArray, outputArray.Length + 1);
                            outputArray[outputArray.Length-1] = inputArray[i];
                        }
            }
            return outputArray;
        }
```

Comment: explain your answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = a.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] == a[j])
                {
                    for (int k = j; k < size; k++)
                    {
                        if (k != size - 1)
                        {
                            int temp = a[k];
                            a[k] = a[k + 1];
                            a[k + 1] = temp;

                        }
                    }
                    j--;
                    size--;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Regretfully this code does not remove anything, so it does not remove duplicates.

Comment: Regretfully the coder does't remove anything either :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicate and ignore case sensitive using Distinct & StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

```
string[] array = new string[] { "A", "a", "b", "B", "a", "C", "c", "C", "A", "1" };
var r = array.Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(r.Count); // return 4 items
```

Comment: The question is "What is the **best** way to remove duplicates from a C# array?". You don't answer that question.

Comment: well read again the question "How do I remove duplicates from a C# array?"

Answer (score 0):

Find answer below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var nums = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9 };
        var result = removeDuplicates(nums);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] nums)
    {
        nums = nums.ToList().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();
        int j = 1;
        int i = 0;
        int stop = 0;
        while (j < nums.Length)
        {
            if (nums[i] != nums[j])
            {
                nums[i + 1] = nums[j];
                stop = i + 2;
                i++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        nums = nums.Take(stop).ToArray();
        return nums;
    }
}
```

Just a bit of contribution based on a test i just solved, maybe helpful and open to improvement by other top contributors here.
Here are the things i did:

1. I used OrderBy which allows me order or sort the items from smallest to the highest using LINQ
2. I then convert it to back to an array and then re-assign it back to the primary datasource
3. So i then initialize j which is my right hand side of the array to be 1 and i which is my left hand side of the array to be 0, i also initialize where i would i to stop to be 0.
4. I used a while loop to increment through the array by going from one position to the other left to right, for each increment the stop position is the current value of i + 2 which i will use later to truncate the duplicates from the array.
5. I then increment by moving from left to right from the if statement and from right to right outside of the if statement until i iterate through the entire values of the array.
6. I then pick from the first element to the stop position which becomes the last i index plus 2. that way i am able to remove all the duplicate items from the int array. which is then reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

So I was doing an interview session and got the same question to sort and distinct

```
static void Sort()
    {
        try
        {
            int[] number = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Array.Sort(number);
            int[] num = number.Distinct().ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with array of objects it worked like this. Choosing which attribute you want to use as a filter;

```
var objectArrayDuplicate = new List<Usuario>();

objectArrayDuplicate.Add(new Usuario { Nome = "Jose", Id = 5 });
objectArrayDuplicate.Add(new Usuario { Nome = "Jose", Id = 5 });
objectArrayDuplicate.Add(new Usuario { Nome = "Maria", Id = 3 });
objectArrayDuplicate.Add(new Usuario { Nome = "Josh", Id = 6 });
 List<Usuario> objectArray = 
objectArrayDuplicate.GroupBy(o => o.Nome).Select(o => o.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             List<int> listofint1 = new List<int> { 4, 8, 4, 1, 1, 4, 8 };
           List<int> updatedlist= removeduplicate(listofint1);
            foreach(int num in updatedlist)
               Console.WriteLine(num);
        }


        public static List<int> removeduplicate(List<int> listofint)
         {
             List<int> listofintwithoutduplicate= new List<int>();


              foreach(var num in listofint)
                 {
                  if(!listofintwithoutduplicate.Any(p=>p==num))
                        {
                          listofintwithoutduplicate.Add(num);
                        }
                  }
             return listofintwithoutduplicate;
         }
    }



}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient way of doing this. Have a look at the other answers to see what they do.

Answer (score -1):

```
strINvalues = "1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4";
strINvalues = string.Join(",", strINvalues .Split(',').Distinct().ToArray());
Debug.Writeline(strINvalues);
```

Kkk Not sure if this is witchcraft or just beautiful code

**1** strINvalues .Split(',').Distinct().ToArray()

**2** string.Join(",", XXX);

*1* Splitting the array and using Distinct [LINQ] to remove duplicates
*2* Joining it back without the duplicates.

Sorry I never read the text on StackOverFlow just the code. it make more sense than the text ;)

Comment: Code-only answers are low-quality answers. Add some explanation to why this works.

Comment: The question is "What is the **best** way to remove duplicates from a C# array?". You don't answer that question.