# How Can I Remove Duplicate Lines From a textBox in C#?

Tags: c#

I have one text box the value is like that below

```
1
2
3
1
3
```

I tried:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", **textBox1.Lines**.Distinct());
```

`textBox1.Lines` is not supporting to my program

Comment: If the text of the textbox is exactly what you wrote ("1 2 3 1 3") there are no duplicate lines, because you have only 1 line

Comment: are you in winforms? what do you mean textBox1.Lines is not supporting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicates from a TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572987/how-can-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-textbox)

Comment: I  want to remove duplicate value only

Answer (score 2):

Add this to using directives at top of page:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then simply use like so:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBox1.Lines.Distinct());
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about that:

```
        string x = "1\r\n2\r\n1\r\n";

        string[] lines = x.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var cmd = (from i in lines select i);
        string[] result = cmd.Distinct().ToArray();

        x = string.Join("\r\n", result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] distinctLines = theText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct().ToArray();
textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", distinctLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the code you posted should work, here's a different approach.

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBox1.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct());
```

Basically, you can split the text into lines yourself since you mention problems with `Lines`.