# How to select items without repetition?

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array)

I have a list of items. I want to select all the items without repetition. How to do that in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the aptly-named [`Distinct()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).
You may need to write an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: Hmmm... knowing what a pedant I am... the OP says "**all** items without repetition", `Distinct` selects a subset of items where each result is unique within the result set ;) You're probably right in what they actually want though.

Comment: @Lazarus: Is there any other way to understand the question? I can't think of one.

Comment: I know it's unlikely but what about a set of data that has common values (i.e. 1,2,2,2,4,1,2,3,1,4,4) but when presented must not have identical values adjacent to one another (i.e. 1,2,4,2,1,2,3,2,4,1,4). Crazy but I've seen much barmier requests here ;) I still think you have the right answer however.

Comment: @SLaks coming from Google and yes, there is another way and not, this answer doen't apply. I don't want the records with duplicates at all: like HAVING COUNT(*) < 2

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
list.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean you want to remove duplicates. Use Distinct

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
var uniqueInts = ints.Distinct();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", uniqueInts));
```