# Removing elements that have consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I was curios about the question: [Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729572/eliminate-consecutive-duplicates-of-list-elements), and how it should be implemented in Python.

What I came up with is this:

```
list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2]
i = 0

while i < len(list)-1:
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        del list[i]
    else:
        i = i+1
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Which I guess is ok.

So I got curious, and wanted to see if I could delete the **elements** that had consecutive duplicates and get this output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

For that I did this:

```
list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2]
i = 0
dupe = False

while i < len(list)-1:
    if list[i] == list[i+1]:
        del list[i]
        dupe = True
    elif dupe:
        del list[i]
        dupe = False
    else:
        i += 1
```

But it seems sort of clumsy and not pythonic, do you have any smarter / more elegant / more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: For very long lists consider using NumPy: [Remove following duplicates in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839928/remove-following-duplicates-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
>>> L = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [key for key, _group in groupby(L)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

---

For the second part

```
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(L) if len(list(g)) < 2]
[2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

If you don't want to create the temporary list just to take the length, you can use sum over a generator expression

```
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(L) if sum(1 for i in g) < 2]
[2, 3, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Note that the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) state that "the iterable needs to already be sorted", which is not the case for the input data here. Still, the proposed solution worked perfectly for the cases I've tested.

Comment: @normanius, to remove all duplicates, the input would need to be sorted. This question is only about removing consecutive duplicates, so you would not want to sort in this case.

Comment: `sum(1 for i in y) < 2` is still somewhat wasteful, looking at every group elements and summing potentially many 1s. `all(0 for _ in y for _ in y)` only looks at up to two group elements. Plus I think it's more interesting :-)

Comment: @Kelly Another idea, more explicit than the nested one: `len(tuple(islice(g, 2))) < 2`. IDK if it would perform differently though.

Comment: @wjandrea Seems to be slightly faster for [short groups](https://tio.run/##lVHbasMwDH33VwhGiT3MyGWF0a1/0D8oYaRFybw6drCV0X59ZjtNu8fOepF0jo5kabjQlzXV2@CmqXW2B1I9KgLVD9YROBywIcY80jjAFrIsY4mmCB1Zq/3C7Jwdh8NFgvJaHZHtAntfyLuVspKvwdbRr@EZijzPg7AhZVAHtj1845G4YLEJQx8FGISX7U/QWgcnCR0os7TiOwGqBT/2vEi4SqCADyjrTD5Q2mjN84R/JvCPKx5T0Gh42IxGPn@bdxJKIf4xg8Ez8TC08mAsXUMJy14SsARRsWbsNqVrTIe8EpvUJ6YxptHPifgobLFXhs@H5BiVw8ASzNgf0G0Leb3xtlwLcSsbnDLEs9VL1ULvIYMVcIo3w0pIwDvxCfCMR55Exfu1Dn8azVHsN2Vez9Q5L6bpFw) and ...

Comment: ... equally fast for [long groups](https://tio.run/##lVFZbsMgEP3nFCNVEVChyksjVWlzg9zAsionGrs0GCzAlXN6F7CzfLbwA/OWeZoZLv7L6PJtsPPcWtODlz1KD7IfjPVgccDGE@LQjwPsgVJKEk16tN4Y5a7MzppxOF4ESKfkCckhsKsJWmNhAqmhysX9FqIUr@Fu47t@IE01PEOZZVkdWmovNargY47fePKMk9ieoIvWBMKh1TmJzwK6qF9DsAMH2YIbe5YnXCaQwwcUNRV/kDZKsSzhnwl8ePK/OSjULMxMIVsGwjoBBef/yKBx8iyElg608etXwHUuCbh@omNNyC2lbXSHrOS71CeWMZbRLYV4fJhiLzVbVswwOofAAvTYH9Huc7Fuf19sOb/JBiu1Z3TzUrbQO6CwAebD0nIsuQC8E58AJzyxZMrfVx3@NIohr3ZFVi/Upc7n@Rc).

Answer (score 32):

**Oneliner in pure Python**

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(your_list) if i == 0 or v != your_list[i-1]]
```

Answer (score 15):

If you use Python 3.8+, you can use assignment expression `:=`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5]

prev = object()
list1 = [prev:=v for v in list1 if prev!=v]

print(list1)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

A "lazy" approach would be to use `itertools.groupby`.

```
import itertools

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5]
list1 = [g for g, _ in itertools.groupby(list1)]
print(list1)
```

outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using `zip_longest()` + list comprehension.

```
from itertools import zip_longest 
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5].
     # using zip_longest()+ list comprehension       
     res = [i for i, j in zip_longest(list1, list1[1:]) 
                                                            if i != j] 
        print ("List after removing consecutive duplicates : " +  str(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without dependence on outside packages:

```
list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2] 
L = list + [999]  # append a unique dummy element to properly handle -1 index
[l for i, l in enumerate(L) if l != L[i - 1]][:-1] # drop the dummy element
```

Then I noted that Ulf Aslak's similar solution is cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

To *Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements*; as an alternative, you may use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest

>>> my_list = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2]
>>> [i for i, j in zip_longest(my_list, my_list[1:]) if i!=j]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of better/more pythonic answers above, however one could also accomplish this task using `list.pop()`:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5]
for x in my_list[:-1]:
    next_index = my_list.index(x) + 1
    if my_list[next_index] == x:
        my_list.pop(next_index)
```

outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible one-liner, using `functools.reduce` (excluding the import) - with the downside that string and list require slightly different implementations:

```py
>>> from functools import reduce

>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[-1:] == [b] else a + [b], [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,1,2], [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]

>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a if a[-1:] == b else a+b, 'aa  bbb cc')
'a b c'
```