# how can i change my list which contains tuple data, to duplicating tuple removed list

Tags: python, list

My list is like this

```
list = [('N',''),('N',''),('K','asdf'),('K','asw'),('S','aqq'),('N',''),('N',''),('N','')]
```

I want change this list to

```
list_1 = [('N',''),('K','asdf'),('K','asdf'),('S','aqq'),('N','')]
```

only duplicated N should be removed..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing elements that have consecutive dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738901/removing-elements-that-have-consecutive-dupes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and grab the first item out of each group using `next`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [('N',''),('N',''),('K','asdf'),('K','asw'),('S','aqq'),('N',''),('N',''),('N','')]
>>> [next(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(l)]
[('N', ''), ('K', 'asdf'), ('K', 'asw'), ('S', 'aqq'), ('N', '')]
```

**Edit**:
If you just want to remove the consecutive duplicates of the tuples starting with `'N'` then you can use

```
>>> [key if key[0] == 'N' else list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(group)) for key, group in itertools.groupby(l)]
[('N', ''), ['K', 'asdf'], ['K', 'asw'], ['S', 'aqq'], ('N', '')]
```

Comment: You can actually use `key` directly instead of `next(group)`.

Comment: Oh, I just want to remove having 'N' tuple. If i use that code, when i change ('K','asw') to ('K','asdf) then 'K' tuple also removed

Comment: @Arcanes See my edit for a solution to that requirement.

Answer (score -1):

simply you can use set to remove duplicates

```
>>> old_list
[('N', ''), ('N', ''), ('K', 'asdf'), ('K', 'asw'), ('S', 'aqq'), ('N', ''), ('N', ''), ('N', '')]
>>> list_1 = list((set(old_list)))
>>> list_1
[('K', 'asdf'), ('N', ''), ('K', 'asw'), ('S', 'aqq')]
```

Comment: `set` doesn't preserve the order!

Comment: The OP only wants to remove consecutive duplicates, not all duplicates

Comment: @arcanes if you want order and to remove consecutive duplicates then my answer not work for you..