# How to remove the adjacent duplicate value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a numpy array, I wish to remove the adjacent duplicate non-zero value and all the zero value. For instance, for an array like that: `[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,0,1,3,3,3]`, I'd like to transform it to: `[1,2,1,3]`. Do you know how to do it? I just know `np.unique(arr)` but it would remove all the duplicate value and keep the zero value. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove following duplicates in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839928/remove-following-duplicates-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `groupby` method from `itertools` combined with list comprehension for this problem:

```
from itertools import groupby
[k for k,g in groupby(a) if k!=0]

# [1,2,1,3]
```

*Data*:

```
a = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,0,1,3,3,3]
```

Comment: any way you can do this in  a multi-dimensional numpy array?

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way:

```
In [62]: x
Out[62]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3])

In [63]: selection = np.ones(len(x), dtype=bool)

In [64]: selection[1:] = x[1:] != x[:-1]

In [65]: selection &= x != 0

In [66]: x[selection]
Out[66]: array([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,0,1,3,3,3])
```

Use [integer indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to choose the non-zero elements

```
b = a[a.nonzero()]

>>> b
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3])
>>>
```

Shift the array to the left and add an element to the end to compare each element with its neighbor.  Use zero since you know there aren't any in `b`.

```
b1 = np.append(b[1:], 0)

>>> b1
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 0])
>>>
```

Use [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to get the values you want.

```
c = b[b != b1]

>>> c
array([1, 2, 1, 3])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as NP
>>> a = NP.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,0,1,3,3,3])
```

first, remove the zeros:

```
>>> idx = a==0
>>> a = a[-idx1]
>>> a
  array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3])
```

now remove the consecutive duplicates

note that *ediff1d(a)* & *a* have different shapes, hence *a1* is not the result; the leading value of a has to be pre-pended to it, as i did in the last three lines below)

```
>>> idx = NP.array(NP.ediff1d(a), dtype=bool)
>>> a1 = a[1:][idx]
  array([2, 1, 3])
```

create an empty array to store the result

```
>>> a0 = NP.empty(shape=(a1.shape[0]+1,))
>>> a0[0] = a[0]
>>> a0[1:] = a1
>>> a0
  array([ 1, 2, 1, 3])
```