# Deleting consecutive numbers from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python but I'm really confused on this project I'm trying to do. I've got an image shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GqIh.png). What I'm trying to do is to find an average across all the squares in the image where the pixel range is from 0 to 255. The code below shows the method I used to calculate the value for the picture. The problem that arises is that the pixels/squares are not the same size where some are bigger than the other. For example, at one instance when looking at a part of the initial picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9D8t.png), the squares are all equal, therefore the arrays are all equal. However in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecvbu.png) picture, we can see that the right hand side squares are smaller than the left hand side ones.

I was thinking of creating a subarray from the original array where, any repeated values are ignored. For example like the one below:

```
1 1 1 2 2 1 2
1 1 1 2 2 1 2
1 1 1 2 2 1 2
1 1 1 2 2 1 2
3 3 3 4 4 1 2
3 3 3 4 4 1 2
5 5 5 6 6 1 2
7 7 7 8 8 1 2
7 7 7 8 8 1 2

to 

1 2 1 2
3 4 1 2
5 6 1 2
7 8 1 2
```

I tried using the following:

```
1. unique_rows = np.unique(data, axis=0)
2. unique_columns = np.unique(unique_rows, axis=1)
```

to get all the not repeated rows to be displayed into a new array from the original and then get all the non-repeated columns from the new array using the 2nd code. Unfortunately, what this does is get rid of all the repeated values. What I want is only get rid of the repeated consecutive values.

I'm really confused on what to do please help!

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('greyscale.png').convert('L')  # convert image to 8-bit grayscale
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size

data = list(img.getdata()) # convert image data to a list of integers
# convert that to 2D list (list of lists of integers)
data = np.array ([data[offset:offset+WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH*HEIGHT, WIDTH)])

#unique_rows = np.unique(data, axis=0)
#unique_columns = np.unique(unique_rows, axis=1)

# At this point the image's pixels are all in memory and can be accessed
# individually using data[row][col].

# For example:
#print data
for row in data:
    print(' '.join('{:3}'.format(value) for value in row))

print np.mean(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked if this solution would work on your whole image rather than on that small sample, and it does work.
I will give an example just for that small array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
              [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2],
              [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2],
              [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 2],
              [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1, 2],
              [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1, 2]])

rows_mask = np.insert(np.diff(x[:, 0]).astype(np.bool), 0, True)
columns_mask = np.insert(np.diff(x[0]).astype(np.bool), 0, True)

print(x[np.ix_(rows_mask, columns_mask)])
```

gives:

```
[[1 2 1 2]
 [3 4 1 2]
 [5 6 1 2]
 [7 8 1 2]]
```

From here you can calculate the average.

---

About getting `rows_mask` and `columns_mask` you can read here: [Remove following duplicates in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839928/remove-following-duplicates-in-a-numpy-array)
.
Also, note that without [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) only diagonal elements would be returned: [Boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Comment: Hi Georgy, thank you so much. I was wondering if this can be applied to a colored image where we have an array like `[0 35 245] [0 35 245] [0 36 240]` where `[0 35 245]` is ignored and `[0 36 240]` is used as the next value?

Comment: @AbidAbdulGafoor This example looks completely different from the one in the original post. I think it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: I've asked a new post now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022577/deleting-consecutive-rgb-values-from-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something smart to be done with `np.diff`, but here is my solution:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('your_image.png').convert('L')
w,h = img.size
a = np.asarray(img.getdata()) # now your image is contained in a long 1D-array
a = np.reshape(a,(h,w)) # reshape from 1D to 2D

# now we delete rows that are duplicates (and later columns)

# initialize b with the first line of a
b = a[0:1,:]
# an index to fill-in b
ib = 0

# scan the lines of a
for ia in range(a.shape[0]-1):
    if (a[ia+1:ia+2,:]!=b[ib, :]).all(): # test for difference
        b = np.concatenate((b,a[ia+1:ia+2,:]), axis=0) # add to b if different
        ib += 1     #increment the index of the current line in b

# now do the same thing with columns. Store the result in c 
c = b[:,0:1]
ic = 0

# scan the columns of b, add to c if different from the last one
for ib in range(b.shape[1]-1):
   if (b[:,ib+1:ib+2]!=c[:,ic]).all():
      c = np.concatenate((c,b[:,ib+1:ib+2]), axis = 1)
      ic += 1
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for helping me out! I've tried this and it works when I have just one column or just one row but when I use the image I attached above, some of the values cannot be seen. There are 12000 squares so should technically have 12000 values in the array. I'll greatly appreciate it if you could help me out. I don't understand where its going wrong...

Comment: Apologies, I read too fast. The code posted above takes an images with duplicates row and columns and eliminate these duplicates. It is not completely clear to me how to obtain this array in the first place. Do you want to replace each block (say 10x10 pixels) by its mean value?

Comment: I want to replace the entire image by a mean value from all the little squares combined but the problem is not all the squares are the same size, so its harder to find the mean value. So I thought I could take the first initial array and then map a new array with only the values for the squares without repetition so a more accurate mean could be found. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have slight edited the code above. Now I think it does what you want: `a` is the array that contains the full image (more or less 936x971 pixels), and `c` is the array where repetitions have been deleted (shape 14x8).