# How to replace repeated numbers in a 1D list with the next non-repeated numbers in the list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very long numpy array which has consequences of repeated values, for example:

```py
My_list = [0.24, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 5, 7, 9, 8.4, 97, 0.56, 34, 0.45, 0.02, 0.02,
           0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23, 27, 32, 37, 45, 0.02, 0.02,
           0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 53, 48, 98, 78,
           564, 343, 3534, 3435, 435, 131, 2435354, 45456, 232]
```

How can I instead of every occurrence of the repeated number 0.02 sequence of varying length in my list, replace them with the "same next numbers sequence appearing after the repetition?

The result should be:

```py
[0.24, 5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8.4, 97, 0.56, 34, 0.45, 0.11, 12,
 0.16, 19, 23, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23, 27, 32, 37, 45, 18, 24,
 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 53, 48, 98, 78,
 564, 343, 3534, 3435, 435, 131, 2435354, 45456, 232]
```

Comment: hi, could u use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839928/remove-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: It only does the removal, not the replacement

Comment: Could you provide a sample output for what you want to do?

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what you are trying to do, both input and output, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: So the result should be `[0.24, 0.02, 5, 5, 5, 7, ...]`?

Comment: Or should it be `[0.24, 5, 7, 9,  5, ...]` or `[0.24, 0.02, 5, 7, 5, ...]`. And, if it is either of these, what would you do if the "next number**s** sequence" spans over another 0.02 ?

Comment: @AngusL'Herrou yes, the output in the above case must be [0.24, 5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8.4, 97, 0.56, 34, 0.45, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23,, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23, 27, 32, 37, 45, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 53, 48, 98, 78, 564, 343, 3534, 3435, 435, 131, 2435354, 45456, 232]

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the list backwards, keeping track of the last known unique value. if you detect a dup, then start replacing the values with the last known value until you stop hitting dups.

```
My_list = [0.24, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 5, 7, 9, 8.4, 97, 0.56, 34, 0.45, 0.02, 0.02,
           0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23, 27, 32, 37, 45, 0.02, 0.02,
           0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 53, 48, 98, 78,
           564, 343, 3534, 3435, 435, 131, 2435354, 45456, 232]

outlist = My_list.copy()
last_unique=My_list[-1]
print("last unique " + str(last_unique))
for i,n in reversed(list(enumerate(My_list))):
    if My_list[i]!=My_list[i-1]:
        print("non equality reassign last unique")
        print(My_list[i],My_list[i-1])
        last_unique=My_list[i]
        print(last_unique)
    elif My_list[i]==My_list[i-1]:
        outlist[i]=last_unique
print(outlist)  


[0.24, 0.02, 5, 5, 5, 7, 9, 8.4, 97, 0.56, 34, 0.45, 0.02, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
0.11, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23, 27, 32, 37, 45, 0.02, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18,  
24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 53, 48, 98, 78, 564, 343, 3534, 3435, 435, 131,  
2435354, 45456, 232]
```

Comment: The constant "0.02" must be replaced by the "numbers" ahead of it in the given list, "not" to repeat the "single" number ahead of it. In the above example, the output should be [0.24, 5, 7, 9, 5, 7, 9, 8.4, 97, 0.56, 34, 0.45, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23,, 0.11, 12, 0.16, 19, 23, 27, 32, 37, 45, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 18, 24, 34, 45, 0.65, 68, 53, 48, 98, 78, 564, 343, 3534, 3435, 435, 131, 2435354, 45456, 232] .

Answer (score 0):

There are two edge cases to consider that you should decide the answers to before solving the problem.

1. What happens if there are fewer than *n* elements in the list after the sequence of *n* repeated elements?
   e.g. `[0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 5]`.
   Do we leave these unchanged:
   `[0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 5]`?
   Or delete the ones we can't replace:
   `[5, 5]`?
   Or replace them with `None`:
   `[5, None, None, 5]`?
2. What happens if the next *n* elements also contain a repeated sequence?
   e.g. `[0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 5, 10, 10, 2, 3, 4]`
   Do we copy left to right:
   `[5, 10, 10, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]`?
   Or right to left:
   `[5, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]`?

Here's a solution that replaces from right to left and leaves unchanged repeated sequences without enough elements to replace them:

```py
def replace_repeats(seq):
    new_seq = seq[:]
    repeat_end = len(seq)
    for i in range(len(seq)-1, -1, -1):
        if i == 0 or seq[i-1] != seq[i]:
            if repeat_end > i + 1 and 2 * repeat_end - i <= len(seq):
                new_seq[i:repeat_end] = new_seq[repeat_end : 2 * repeat_end - i]
            repeat_end = i
    return new_seq
```

Comment: Thanks much for your eye-opening comments. To address the first case, having 'None' or "unchanged" won't work. It has to be similar behavior in adjacent data, so I could think of using "average" of those non_repeated values to fill in the required empty spaces,

Comment: and to address the 2nd case, the repeated number to avoid here is only the constant value of "0.02" which must be replaced by the same number of items following ahead of it. The only edge case then becomes if the 0.02 repetitions happen at the end of the list, which either we would replace them by the numbers proceeding them, or we could reverse the list from the beginning and work from the right to left as you suggested.

Comment: I would recommend exploring all the possible edge cases of the problem and deciding what you want the behavior to be in each one. This will help you structure the logic of your code, as you will know what decisions need to be made depending on the characteristics of the input. Then you can ask more focused questions about how to address specific aspects of the problem that you can't figure out.