# How to remove consecutive duplicates in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, duplicates, unique, tensor

For example, input a 1-d tensor:

```
l_in = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,1,3,5]
```

I want to remove the **consecutive duplicates**, which means the output should be:

```
l_out = [1,2,3,4,5,1,3,5]
```

However, the `tf.unique` function only returns **unique elements**, indicating that the last three elements will also be eliminated. The output of `tf.unique` is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5], [0,0,1,1,2,3,4,4,0,2,4] = tf.unique(l_in)
```

where the second item is the corresponding IDs.

Is there any way to only remove consecutive duplicates while preserving non-duplicated and non-unique elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For 1D tensors, using array rotation/shifting:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

l_in = tf.constant([1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,1,3,5])
l_left_shift = tf.concat((l_in[1:], [0]), axis=0)
mask_left_shift = tf.not_equal(l_in - l_left_shift, 0)
mask = tf.concat(([True], mask_left_shift[:-1]), axis=0)
l_out = tf.boolean_mask(l_in, mask)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(l_out))
# [1 2 3 4 5 1 3 5]
```

(i.e. the idea is to subtract each element with its right neighbor, then mask out the neighbor if the subtraction result is 0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a neat and brilliant idea!

Comment: Not gonna lie, but this was very clever solution. It's shame that even after these many years TensorFlow team is not able to provide a standalone function that do this. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

Don't know about tensorflow, but since it seems to be a simple list you can use groupby from itertools quite easily:

```
from itertools import groupby  
l_out = [x[0] for x in groupby(l_in)]
print(l_out) # prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 5]
```

See also: [Removing elements that have consecutive duplicates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738901/removing-elements-that-have-consecutive-duplicates-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your information. I've noticed that answer before I opened this question, but I didn't find a corresponding solution in tensorflow.