# Python Subsetting a list with changing value in list

Tags: python, list

I would like to get a list of values that change from the previous value from a larger list. I have tried creating the list by looping over the larger list, but I'm hoping there is a better way to do this, because i would like to save time searching over a large list.

```
sublist= [largerList[0]]
previous = largerList[0]
for item in largerList:
    if item != previous:
        sublist.append(item)
        previous = item
```

if

```
LargerList = [10,10,10,10,10,0,10,10,10,10,15,15,15,15,15,10,10,0,10,10,12,12,12,0]
```

I want

```
sublist = [10,0,10,15,10,0,10,12,0]
```

Comment: Well you cannot do better than O(n) which is iterating over the entire list, so what you have seems good enough

Comment: You did it with just one loop over the large list. I think this is the best you will get. You might find a function that does exactly that in some library and then your code will be one line but the function you will find is probably iterating over the large list as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements that have consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738901/removing-elements-that-have-consecutive-duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to do this efficiently with less code. It still needs to look at every item. By default `groupby` will group by value, and the key will be the value of the groups. So just collect the keys:

```
from itertools import groupby

LargerList = [10,10,10,10,10,0,10,10,10,10,15,15,15,15,15,10,10,0,10,10,12,12,12,0]
sublists = [k for k, _ in groupby(LargerList)]
```

**Sublists:**

```
[10, 0, 10, 15, 10, 0, 10, 12, 0]
```

Comment: Perhaps `sublists = [k for k, _ in groupby(LargerList)]` since we are not using `g`