# Merge two lists to create a list which contains items of the two lists as lists

Tags: python, list, merge, coordinates

I would like to merge two lists:

`lon: [14.21055347, 14.21055347, 16.39356558, 16.39356558, 14.21055347]`

`lat: [48.22824817, 48.22824817, 48.18617251, 48.18617251, 47.65823679]`

to get:

`coordinates: [[14.21055347, 48.22824817], [14.21055347, 48.22824817], [16.39356558, 48.18617251], [16.39356558, 48.18617251], [14.21055347, 47.65823679]]`

How is this done efficiently for very long lists of lon/lat?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: coordinates = list(zip(lon,lat))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) built-in function as well as [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

```py
lon = [14.21055347, 14.21055347, 16.39356558, 16.39356558, 14.21055347]
lat = [48.22824817, 48.22824817, 48.18617251, 48.18617251, 47.65823679]

coordinates = list(map(lambda x, y: [x, y], lon, lat))

print(coordinates)
>>> [[14.21055347, 48.22824817], [14.21055347, 48.22824817], [16.39356558, 48.18617251], [16.39356558, 48.18617251], [14.21055347, 47.65823679]]
```

Comment: Python's in-built zip command is more efficient than this.

Comment: The `zip` function returns an iterator of tuples, which is not exactly what the post wants.

Comment: I know that. I'm just mentioning that a list of tuples is a better data structure for such purposes and `zip` function is an efficient way.  There's nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly how I needed it! One more question if I may - is there a way to remove only those dublicates that are successive? BRG

Comment: You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738933/4141606) for some examples.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function for that. Like most of python3 built-ins it uses iterators so is quite performant.

```
>>> lon = [14.21055347, 14.21055347, 16.39356558, 16.39356558, 14.21055347]
>>> lat = [48.22824817, 48.22824817, 48.18617251, 48.18617251, 47.65823679]
>>> coordinates = zip(lon, lat)
>>> print(list(coordinates))
[(14.21055347, 48.22824817), (14.21055347, 48.22824817), (16.39356558, 48.18617251), (16.39356558, 48.18617251), (14.21055347, 47.65823679)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lon = [14.21055347, 14.21055347, 16.39356558, 16.39356558, 14.21055347]
lat = [48.22824817, 48.22824817, 48.18617251, 48.18617251, 47.65823679]

coordinates = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(lon, lat)]

print(coordinates)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but if you want to match the two arrays, just do:

name = [array1, array2]

Comment: The OP want's each element to be combined.

Answer (score -1):

Just use map function

```
lon = [14.21055347, 14.21055347, 16.39356558, 16.39356558, 14.21055347]
lat = [48.22824817, 48.22824817, 48.18617251, 48.18617251, 47.65823679]
coordinates = list(map(lambda x,y: [x,y], lon,lat))
print(coordinates)
```

output is :-
[[14.21055347, 48.22824817], [14.21055347, 48.22824817], [16.39356558, 48.18617251], [16.39356558, 48.18617251], [14.21055347, 47.65823679]]

Map takes as an input a function so had to introduce the lambda function