# How can I select a specific number in a list with duplicates without removing the previous same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates

I have the following list in python3:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I want to have something like this as an output:

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

How can I do that? I have tried `a = set(a)` and other methods for getting rid of duplicates. But they remove all duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing elements that have consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738901/removing-elements-that-have-consecutive-duplicates)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. In the future, please try some research first. I found that question by googling `python compress adjacent duplicates`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a module, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]

output = [k for k, _ in groupby(a)]
print(output) # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
b = [a[0]]
for k in a:
    if k!=b[-1]:
        b.append(k)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you comfortable with C, you may like this style:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
b=len(a)
i=0
last_one=None
while i<b:
    if a[i]==last_one:
        del a[i]
        b-=1
        continue
    else:
        last_one=a[i]
    i+=1
print(a)
```