# How to check if multiple same elements are next to each other without sorting in python

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list

```
[0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1]
```

And output I would want for this list would be:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

My first thought was to do by sorting but I still want elements to remain as they are with the example of the ones above and in the same order. How would I do this?

I would prefer pseudocode, hints, or python please!

Comment: How would you solve this with a pen + paper?

Comment: I'm sorry that's why I'm asking, I'm not the best at thinking of doing it on pen+paper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing elements that have consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738901/removing-elements-that-have-consecutive-duplicates)

Comment: @JisooKim If you can't solve it manually, how could you ever translate it into code? I bet if you tried on paper you could figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you, this exact behavior is provided as a recipe in official Python docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Example usage:

```py
list(unique_justseen([0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1]))
# => [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to use itertools:

```
lst = [0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1]

res = lst[0:1]
for item in lst:
    if res[-1] != item:
        res.append(item)

print(res) #=> [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator and keep track of the previous value:

```
def unique_just_seen(iterable):
    previous = object()  # ensures the first value in the iterable is yielded
    for item in iterable:
        if item != previous:
            yield item
            previous = item

print(list(unique_just_seen([0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1]))) # [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip fo compare items with their predecessor:

```
a = [0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1]

b = a[:1] + [n for p,n in zip(a,a[1:]) if n!=p]

print(b)
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```