# How can I make a generic list passed and returned as IEnumerable<T> return a proper value instead of null?

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, enumerable

I'm just trying to solve various code katas, and have been stuck on the final piece of this problem for hours.  The purpose is to return a result that doesn't have a repeating digit or character adjacent to it, while remaining in order.  I've passed all the tests except one called ListTest, so I've tried to determine how to make a List argument return a value.  Well, it always returns null thus far.  I could use a push or hint in the right direction.

I can't remember everything I've tried, but the basic setup I have is an if statement checking for generic lists, and then running a separate code branch if that's the case.  I'm not even sure that is necessary.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> UniqueInOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable)
            {
                string strArr = String.Empty;
                string strLast = String.Empty;

                List<dynamic> strList = new List<dynamic>();

                var enumerator = iterable.GetEnumerator();

                for (int i = 0; i < iterable.Count(); i++)
                {
                    enumerator.MoveNext();

                    if (enumerator.Current.ToString() == strLast)
                        continue;
                    strArr += enumerator.Current.ToString();
                    strLast = enumerator.Current.ToString();
                }

                if (iterable is IList && iterable.GetType().IsGenericType)
                {
                    foreach (var l in strArr)
                    {
                        strList.Add(l);
                    }
                    return strList as IEnumerable<T>;
                }
                return strArr as IEnumerable<T>;

            }

            static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(UniqueInOrder("AABBCDEE"));
                Console.WriteLine(UniqueInOrder("112334557"));
                Console.WriteLine(UniqueInOrder(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }));
            }
```

This is what my original code looked like before I tried throwing the kitchen sink at it to fix it.

[image]

The answer was provided by Chetan in the comments, so this is now solved.

Comment: Which call to `UniqueInOrder` method returns null? Which line of code gives you null?

Comment: The last one with new List<int> {1, 2, 3}, and everything looks fine with it until it actually returns.

Comment: `strList` is not `IEnumerable<T>`... it is `IEnumerbale<dynamic>`... Why do you expect cast to succeed? (Side note: it may be a good idea to explain what is expected from this code - link, or better yet inline the assignment you trying to solve)

Comment: `return strList as IEnumerable<T>;` is the issue... `strList` is `List<dynamic>` and `IEnumerable<T>` will be `IEnumerable<int>` in the last method call... so that conversion does not happen and it returns null.

Comment: I see what you are both saying, but what would I use to return it as a valid value?  I was previously not using any list syntax in the UniqueInOrder method, and it still passed out null using the return strArr as IEnumerable<T>.  Here is a link to the problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/54e6533c92449cc251001667/train/csharp

Comment: There are a lot of red flags in this code. I strongly doubt you need a `List<dynamic>` and I doubt you need to use Reflection to solve this problem.

Comment: What I believe is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729572/eliminate-consecutive-duplicates-of-list-elements) shows correct solution and hopefully self-explanatory. If not at least it should give you some ideas to clarify what exactly you don't understand...

Comment: The problem isn't with me being able to deduce the solution to the consecutive elements part, I've already passed 5 of 6 tests.  It's only when the argument itself is a list.  It has to be returned as an IEnumerable<T>, that is what I do not know how to do without it becoming nullified.

Comment: If this is a duplicate, then it would mean the duplicate had the answer, which it doesn't not provide.

Comment: Guess I'll need to re-word this question since nobody has a clue what I'm talking about.

Comment: @JohnWu's comment's value cannot be overstated. The code you posted is wrong for pretty much every kind of input except a `string` value (which happens to be `IEnumerable<char>`). Your specification is also suspect: lists of integers cannot have adjacent "digits" or "characters"; each element is a whole number unto itself. The 2nd-highest-voted answer in the marked duplicate is a good general solution to what would be a corrected version of your stated specification, so you should look more closely at that. That your method returns `null` is just a side-effect of everything else wrong with it.

Comment: _"nobody has a clue what I'm talking about"_ -- Nobody? I don't see anyone that doesn't know what you're talking about, but even if _someone_ doesn't, "nobody" is certainly too broad. Bottom line: you're asking about the `null` return value, which is clearly just because your code is unredeemably broken (you're trying to cast a reference to a type that it's not, using `as`, so of course you get `null`). You need a completely different approach, which the marked duplicate illustrates quite well.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zo6HCm here is a simpler implementation of your method.

Comment: To solve the issue you are facing @StarnesStudent you need difference approach to solve the problem. With the current version of your method `null` object error can not be resolved for sure....Even if the duplicate answer is not acceptable by you the current approach still need to change.

Comment: I get I'm coming off a little hot-headed, so I apologize for that.  I have implemented the duplicate's suggestion, and an in the process of rewriting this so it is clearer what the final problem is.

Comment: Nm, Chetan has the answer.  Thank you Chetan.

Comment: @Chetan's code is not different in any material way from the code in the marked duplicate. So your question is in fact a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Peter, my problem was not removing the adjacent duplicates, it was determining how to return the value as an IEnumerable<T>.  Chetan's code accounted for that.  While I am not doubting you that the other code works, it requires me to solve the problem I was asking to understand how to re-work it into the context of the solution.  When I plugged the other solution into my code, it presented with errors on several fronts that I did not know how to fix.  I changed "array" to "iterable", but the results.Last() != element was giving me an issue because it says != can't be applied to string and T.