# How to get distinct values from an array in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array)

How to get distinct values from an array in C#

Comment: .Distinct()?

Questions with nothing in it deserve nothing more as an answer...

Comment: int[] MyArray = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4};
int[] MyDistinctArray  = MyArray.Distinct().ToArray();

Will give you 

MyDistinctArray  = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}

Answer (score 34):

You could use the [`.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) extension method.

```
var collectionWithDistinctElements = oldArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10):

Using [`Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) function:

```
var distinctArray = myArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: Your dinstincts are correct :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Distinct` method in LINQ.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

```
            List<int> ages = new List<int> { 21, 46, 46, 55, 17, 21, 55, 55 };

            IEnumerable<int> distinctAges = ages.Distinct();

            Console.WriteLine("Distinct ages:");

            foreach (int age in distinctAges)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(age);
            }

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             Distinct ages:
             21
             46
             55
             17
            */
```

Answer (score 2):

`Distinct` should suffice your problem, but if you are doing this on custom object you will need to implement `IEquatable<T>` and will need to override `GetHashCode()` method to make it work.