# How to delete duplicate values in an array?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array)

I have an int array which contains a defined number of elements, all positive. I want to get an array from this one where all the elements appear only once. e.g. If the first array was something like `{2000,2011,2011,2012,2009,2009,2000}`, I want to get this `{2000,2011,2012,2009}`. How can I do this? I tried lots of things with for loops but I can't manage to do something good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With LINQ it's easy:

```
var intArray = new[] { 2000, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2009, 2009, 2000 };
var uniqueArray = intArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx

Another way is using [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx):

```
uniqueArray = intArray.GroupBy(i => i).Select(grp => grp.Key).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

you can do the below

```
var yourArray = yourArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx

Comment: That will only create an IEnumerable, not an array. To return a new array you need to call ToArray on the result. Something like: `yourArray = yourArray.Distinct().ToArray();`

Comment: I have edited my answer even if it was just to give to the OP the right direction to go

Comment: Note that the value returned by `Distinct` is not guaranteed to be ordered.  If you want it ordered by the values, use `yourArray.Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray()`.  If maintaining the original insertion order is important, (as your example might suggest) you might want to take a slower option like Efthimis's (but I'd recommend `List<T>` over `ArrayList`, which is outdated).

Comment: in this case the order is not important as you can see by looking at the output {2000,2011,2012,2009}

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way:

```
    int[] _array = new int[] {1, 2, 1,2}
    var myArray = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

    foreach(var item in _array){
        if (!myArray.Contains(item))
            myArray.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you may want to look at a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), especially if you know ahead of time you will have duplicate values.