# Delete duplicated element from array from split string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have a question about deleting duplicates from array list. I want to join two strings from two tables and then split it. Compare the string from one table with others, if duplicates exist then delete it.
I did it with this code but i'm asking if there is another faster and shorter way to do it?

table1: `String a = "abc"`

table2: `String b = "def,abc,okl"`

Result: `"abc,def,okl"`

My code:

```
foreach(DataRow tr in transM.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataRow tb in tableDGV1.Rows)
    {
        if (tr["ID"].ToString() == tb["ID"].ToString())
        {
            string trMitter = tr["Tr"].ToString() + "," + tb["Tr"].ToString();
            string[] trSplit = trMitter.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<string> listTr = new List<string>(trSplit);

            for (int k = 0; k < listTr.Count; k++)
            {
                for (int g = k + 1; g < listTr.Count; g++)
                {
                    if (listTr[g].ToString() == listTr[k].ToString()) listTr.RemoveAt(g);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I you are using .Net V 3.5 or later, you can simply use `var firstSource = firstString.Split(','); var secondeSource = secondString.Split(',');var result = firstSource.Union(secondSource);`

Comment: This question should be moved to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are using .Net V 3.5 or later, you can simply use

```
var firstSource = firstString.Split(','); 
var secondeSource = secondString.Split(',');
var result = firstSource.Union(secondSource);`
```

Or use `.Distinct()`:

```
foreach(DataRow tr in transM.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataRow tb in tableDGV1.Rows)
    {
        if (tr["ID"].ToString() == tb["ID"].ToString())
        {
            string trMitter = tr["Tr"].ToString() + "," + tb["Tr"].ToString();
            string[] trSplit = trMitter.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            IEnumerable<string> noDuplicate = trSplit.Distinct();              

        }
    }
}
```

Or in more Linqish style :

```
var noDuplicate = from DataRow row1 in transM.Rows
                  from DataRow row2 in tableDGV1.Rows
                  where row1["ID"].Equals(row2["ID"])
                  let array1 = row1["tr"].ToString().Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  let array2 = row2["tr"].ToString().Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  select array1.Union(array2).Distinct();
```

Comment: after `var result = firstSource.Union(secondSource);` to show the result i use `tb["Tr"] = result` ?

Comment: Use a simple `foreach(var item in result) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the big performance hit is on the loops on the table rows.
You could optimize your query using this (if the ID column is the primary key)

```
foreach(DataRow tr in transM.Rows)
{
    string idValue = tr["ID"].ToString();
    DataRow[] foundRows = tableDGV1.Select("ID = " + idValue);
    if(foundRows.Length == 1)
    {
       // Here you have the internal row to join with the external one
        string joinedString = tr["Tr"].ToString() + "," + foundRows[0]["Tr"].ToString();
        string[] trSplit = joinedString.Split(new char[] {','}, 
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        List<string> listTr = trSplit.Distinct().ToList();                        
        .........
    }
}
```

this will remove the unnecessary loops on the internal table

Answer (score 0):

You can create first a list with all the elements, sort the list and remove the duplicates.
There are a related question here: [Remove duplicates from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array)

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable.Union()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) method removes duplicates:

```
var items1 = new[] { "abc" };
var items2 =  "def,abc,okl";

var splitItems2 = items2.Split(',');

var result = 
    items1.Union(splitItems2) // Removes duplicates
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) which produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality comparer.

```
        string[] id1 = { "abc" };
        string[] id2 = { "def", "abc", "okl" };

        IEnumerable<string> both = id2.Union(id1);

        foreach (string id in both)
            Console.WriteLine(id);
```