# Optimized way to remove duplicate values of a given array

Tags: java, c#, c

Recently I was asked a very tricky question in an interview.

1. Given an array like (just for example) [image]
2. Now write an optimized algorithm (without using in build feature except the basic one like for loop etc.) so that the output does not contain duplicate values.

**Please Note:** Of course we can do it having 2 for loops, but its not optimized. They wanted an optimized solution.

Comment: possible help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c# just use the System.Linq `Distinct` method.

#### Sample

```
var stringArray = { "0", "1", "5", "65", "r" };
var uniqueStringArray = stringArray.Distinct().ToArray();
```

#### More Information

- [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @dknaack: Thanks for the quick answer, actually they have asked to write the algorithm without using inbuilt classes/methods. Or in other words, like implement the DISTINCT() method... :)

Comment: @ismailbaig I guess he wants the most efficient way to do that. No word about not using inbuilt features.

Comment: @dknaack: i have edited the quesiton now as per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modified merge sort. You represent your array as two arrays, and them merge them, but when you find equal values on merge operation you throw out one of them.

Comment: Which in O(n log n) overall.

Answer (score 0):

In LinQ its possible

```
strarray = Your array.
strarray.Distinct().ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# you can do:

```
var result = new HashSet<string>(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java put the Array into Set

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

In java you can add all elements into [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) using [`Collections#addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29)

```
Set<T> data = new HashSet<T>();
Collections.addAll(data, yourArray);
```

PS : Set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Answer (score 0):

`var stringArray = { "0", "1", "5", "65", "r" };
var uniqueStringArray = stringArray.Distinct().ToArray();